# Getting issues while assigning reader role to storage account via ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am facing following error "The request to create role assignment 'c*****************5' is not valid. Role assignment scope '/subscriptions/c**********************5/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mystorageaccountname' must match the scope specified on the URI"

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "principalId": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "My AD app ID",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The principal to assign the role to"
            }
        },
        "builtInRoleType": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Reader",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Owner",
                "Contributor",
                "Reader"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Built-in role to assign"
            }
        },
        "roleNameGuid": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "random guid (i am getting this guid using following PS command "[System.Guid]::NewGuid().toString()")",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "A new GUID used to identify the role assignment"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "Owner": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'this is my ownerid')]",
        "Contributor": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'this is my contributor id')]",
        "Reader": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'this is my reader id')]",
        "scope": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', 'this is my storage account name')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2014-10-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('roleNameGuid')]",
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables(parameters('builtInRoleType'))]",
                "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]",
                "scope": "[variables('scope')]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem for assigning a role assignment at a scope higher than the scope of the deployment. In your case the deployment is at the Resource Group level and you are trying to assign the scope at the Subscription level (which is higher level than Resource Group).

**Solution**: You will need to use Nested Template deployment.

To view a sample, check this documentation link and search for section "Assign Role at Scope" in this documentation: [Create resources at Subscription level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/deploy-to-subscription#assign-role-at-scope)